# Django Error: "The view auctions.views.new_bid didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm getting the error: "The view auctions.views.new_bid didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Does anyone know why it is returning None? Any help is appreciated.

This view will allow a user to bid on an item on a site, similar to ebay.
new_bid allows them to bid and listingpage is to show the actual item's page.
The listing page loads fine, I just get the error when I place a number in the bid form, and save. In the `/admin` section of the site I can see the number is not saving.

views.py:

```py
    def new_bid(request, listingid):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            auction_to_add = Listings.objects.get(id=listingid)
            total_bid = request.POST.get("total_bid")
            bid = Bid.objects.create(user=request.user, listingid=auction_to_add, bid=total_bid)
            auction_to_add.bids.add(bid)
            auction_to_add.last_bid = bid
            auction_to_add.save()
            return HttpResponse('success')
           


    def listingpage(request, listingid):
        comments = Comments.objects.filter(listingid=listingid)
        item = Listings.objects.get(id=listingid)
        return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
            "listingid": listingid,
            "comments": comments,
            "product": item,
        })
```

Part of html for the listingpage that allows a user to place a bid:

```
<form id="addBid" data-startingbid="{{product.starting_bid}}" data-lastbid=" 
  {{product.last_bid.bid}}" data-auction="{{product.id}}" action="{% url 'new_bid' 
product.id %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="number" name="totalBid" id="newBid" placeholder="Total bid">
                    <button class="button-auction" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    path("listings/<int:listingid>", views.listingpage, name="listingpage"),
    path("new_bid/<int:listingid>", views.new_bid, name="new_bid"),
]
```

models.py

```
class Bid(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    bid = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    listingid = models.ForeignKey('Listings', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='listing_for_bid')


class Listings(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    starting_bid = models.IntegerField()
    bids = models.ManyToManyField('Bid', related_name='bids_in_the_auction', blank=True)
    last_bid = models.ForeignKey('Bid', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='last_bid_for_the_auction', blank=True,
                             null=True)
```

Comment: You made a GET request, since you did not specify `method="post"` in the `<form>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `new_bid(request, listingid)` function does not return anything (therefore returns None) when the request method is not POST.

Now, you didn't specify a method in your form and thus it defaults to GET. The following change should do it:

```py
<form id="addBid" data-startingbid="{{product.starting_bid}}" data-lastbid=" 
  {{product.last_bid.bid}}" data-auction="{{product.id}}" action="{% url 'new_bid' 
product.id %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="number" name="totalBid" id="newBid" placeholder="Total bid">
                    <button class="button-auction" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you @dacx - I added your change and it definitely helped. However, the code in views.py is still not taking in the number I submit as the bid. It returns None and I don't know why. I can't use a debugger in my IDE because it's using the Django framework - any advice?